# Proof that -fomit-frame-pointer interferes with gdb

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb

I heard that `-fomit-frame-pointer` interferes with gdb and when you use `bt` you should get like one frame only #0.

I created such a file:

```
#include <iostream>

void __attribute__ ((noinline))  bar(int i)
{
    printf("!!!%d\n", i);
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo(int i)
{
    bar(i);
}

int main()
{
    int q;

    int e = scanf("%d", &q);
    (void) e;

    foo(q);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as `g++ -o a a.cpp -O0 -fomit-frame-pointer` and can see in gdb that there are now no `push rbp; move rsp rbp` epilogue/prologue.

However, when I put breakpoint at `printf`, I get the full stacktrace:

```
Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x555555556004 "!!!%d\n") at ./stdio-common/printf.c:28
28      ./stdio-common/printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __printf (format=0x555555556004 "!!!%d\n") at ./stdio-common/printf.c:28
#1  0x00005555555551f1 in bar(int) ()
#2  0x000055555555520d in foo(int) ()
#3  0x0000555555555253 in main ()
```

Do I miss anything? Or is my example too simple? Or is my information on `-fomit-frame-pointer` is wrong?

Comment: Gcc documentation used to warn that the option [makes debugging impossible on some machines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). The current version [no longer contains such a warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). Can you expand on what you heard (where...)?

Comment: So maybe it makes sense to try an older compiler? @teapot418

Comment: I don't think the 'some machines' actually ever included x86-64. Also the warning  may have been directed at third-party tools that are not gdb and blindly rely on frame pointers. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628186/how-fomit-frame-pointer-gcc-option-could-make-debugging-impossible

Comment: So on x86-64 there is also a low chance to see the "empty bt" showing only one frame? @teapot418

Comment: Not because of omitted frame pointers. You still may get the effect with a corrupted stack.

Comment: I see. Thank you! @teapot418

Comment: If you do `strip -R .eh_frame a` before running GDB, do you get the same stack trace, or do you get something that looks like GDB has used heuristics to identify frames?